# Scala GUI - add a scrollbar to a textArea

Tags: java, swing, scala, user-interface, scrollpane

I'm trying to make a textArea scrollable with **scala swing**,

Here's what I have so far:

```
import scala.swing._

object messages extends TextArea{
    preferredSize = new Dimension(600,340)
}

val frame = new MainFrame{
    contents = new FlowPanel{
        val outputTextScrollPane = new ScrollPane(messages) 
        contents += outputTextScrollPane
    }
}
```

The problem is the text-area still don't have any scrollbar... Am I missing something or isn't this the right way to add a scrollbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred size of `TextArea` is specified by a number of rows and columns, it seems that setting `preferredSize` is messing it up. If you use the following, it works:

```
object messages extends TextArea(rows = 40, columns = 60)
```